# Row background color on click JavaFX

Tags: javafx, colors, tableview

is there any chance to code TableView row color on selected row? I mean something like that: I have for example TableView filled with movies and I want a specific movie (row) to change color on click to - green when it is in shop - or - to red - when it is not in shop. We will know if it is in shop or not by making simple function with query to database, but I also need some function which will be able to change selected row background color. Is there any way to make with code something like that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of:

```
TableView<Movie> table = ... ;

PseudoClass outOfStockPseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("out-of-stock");

table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<Movie> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
        if (isNowSelected) {
            boolean outOfStock = checkIfOutOfStock(row.getItem()) ;
            row.pseudoClassStateChanged(outOfStockPseudoClass, outOfStock);
        }
    });
    row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldMovie, newMovie) -> {
        if (row.isSelected()) {
            boolean outOfStock = checkIfOutOfStock(newMovie) ;
            row.pseudoClassStateChanged(outOfStockPseudoClass, outOfStock);
        }
    });
    return row ;
});
```

And then in your external CSS file do

```css
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-selection-bar: /* color for in-stock selected row */ ;
}
.table-row-cell:out-of-stock {
    -fx-selection-bar: /* color for out-of-stock selected row */;
}
```

If you can check whether the movie is in stock at the time you initialize the data from the database, you can simplify your row factory:

```
table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Movie>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Movie item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        pseudoClassStateChanged(outOfStockPseudoClass, 
            item!=null && item.isOutOfStock());
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm this might work but color is not chaning : / external CSS file is standard application.css ? do I have to link it to application to work or something? I mean, can i somehow do it without pseudoClass, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889732/javafx-tableview-change-row-color-based-on-column-value and yes, on tableview initialization or refresh I wont make query check if that movie is in stock or not?