# JavaFX tableview with CSS scrolling issue

Tags: javafx

I am currently facing a problem with javafx table. I have a tableview that shows a list of subjects. The background color of each row depends if a subject is able to be enrolled or not. Subjects with green background can be enrolled and subjects with pink background cannot be enrolled. The problem occurs when scrolling the table.

[TableView before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI37r.png)

[TableView after scrolling down and up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCLiI.png)

After scrolling, the background color of rows have changed and the subjects with green background might become pink and vice versa. This works perfectly without adding a css to the table.

**Code I used to set the background color of rows**

```
tblAvailableSubjects.setRowFactory((TableView<Subject> param) -> {
            TableRow<Subject> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isEmpty) -> {
                if(isEmpty) {
                    row.setContextMenu(null);
                    row.setStyle("-fx-border-color: transparent");
                } else {

                    Subject subject = row.getItem();

                    if(subject.getSubjectEvaluation().equals(SubjectEvaluation.COMPLETED)) {
                        row.setStyle("-fx-background: #B2EBF2");
                    } else if(subject.getSubjectEvaluation().equals(SubjectEvaluation.FAILED)) {
                        row.setStyle("-fx-background: #FF0000");
                        row.setContextMenu(tblAvailableContext);
                    } else if(subject.getSubjectEvaluation().equals(SubjectEvaluation.OKAY)) {
                        row.setStyle("-fx-background: #8BC34A");
                        row.setContextMenu(tblAvailableContext);
                    } else if(subject.getSubjectEvaluation().equals(SubjectEvaluation.ENROLLWITHCOREQ)) {
                        row.setStyle("-fx-background: #FFEB3B");
                        row.setContextMenu(tblAvailableContext);
                    } else if(subject.getSubjectEvaluation().equals(SubjectEvaluation.CANTENROLL)) {
                        row.setStyle("-fx-background: #FFCDD2");
                    }
                }
            });
            return row;
        });
```

**CSS for table**

```
.table-view {
    /*     Constants used throughout the tableview. */
    -fx-table-header-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: -fx-box-border;
    /*    Horizontal Lines*/
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .filler, .table-view .column-header
{
    -fx-size: 40;
    -fx-border-style: null;
    -fx-border-color: rgb(200.0, 200.0, 200.0);
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .show-hide-columns-button
{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .column-header .label,
.table-view .column-drag-header .label
{
    -fx-alignment: CENTER_LEFT;
}

.table-view .column-header-background
{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-row-cell {
    -fx-cell-size: 30px;
}

.table-cell {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
}
```

EDIT: The subject's SubjectEvaluation value doesn't change, it seems that it switches the context menu and background color between rows when scrolling.

I hope someone could help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you `if(isEmpty) {
                    row.setContextMenu(null);
                    row.setStyle(null);
                } `?

Comment: @Sedrick nothing has changed. The problem still occurs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889732/javafx-tableview-change-row-color-based-on-column-value

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.